# Making a Zsync file archive with checksums

Tags: file, go, casting, checksum

I'm learning go by doing it. I tried to port the Java's ZsyncMake [implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/salesforce/zsync4j/master/zsync-core/src/main/java/com/salesforce/zsync/ZsyncMake.java) into Golang.
I also employ the Go's concurrency API with goroutine and channel.
I have some experience in Java, but never work with native language. One immediately coming problem is `int` in Golang isn't the same as `int32` (since it depends on the platform; Java's `int` is 4 byte), thus I need to cast it most of the time.

Here's my code. In some comments I wrote `[ASK]` to indicate that I'm not sure if it's a proper way of implementation in Go

```
package zsync

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "goZsyncmake/md4"
    "goZsyncmake/zsyncOptions"
    "hash"
    "io"
    "log"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var ZSYNC_VERSION = "0.6.2"
var BLOCK_SIZE_SMALL = 2048
var BLOCK_SIZE_LARGE = 4096

func ZsyncMake(path string, options zsyncOptions.Options) {
    checksum, headers, zsyncFilePath := writeToFile(path, options)
    zsyncFile, err := os.Create(zsyncFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer zsyncFile.Close()

    bfio := bufio.NewWriter(zsyncFile)
    _, err = bfio.WriteString(headers)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = bfio.Write(checksum)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bfio.Flush()
}

func writeToFile(path string, options zsyncOptions.Options) ([]byte, string, string) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    outputFileName := file.Name() + ".zsync"

    fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    opts := calculateMissingValues(options, file)

    blockSize := opts.BlockSize
    fileLength := fileInfo.Size()
    sequenceMatches := 0
    if fileLength > int64(options.BlockSize) {
        sequenceMatches = 2
    } else {
        sequenceMatches = 1
    }
    weakChecksumLength := weakChecksumLength(fileLength, blockSize, sequenceMatches)
    strongChecksumLength := strongChecksumLength(fileLength, blockSize, sequenceMatches)

    fileDigest := sha1.New()
    blockDigest := md4.New()

    checksum, fileChecksum := computeChecksum(file, blockSize, fileLength, weakChecksumLength, strongChecksumLength, fileDigest, blockDigest)
    strFileChecksum := hex.EncodeToString(fileChecksum)

    // [ASK] I suspect I can improve performance here rather than appending string with +
    strHeader := "zsync: " + ZSYNC_VERSION + "\n" +
        "Filename: " + fileInfo.Name() + "\n" +
        "MTime: " + fileInfo.ModTime().Format(time.RFC1123Z) + "\n" +
        "Blocksize: " + strconv.Itoa(blockSize) + "\n" +
        "Length: " + strconv.Itoa(int(fileLength)) + "\n" +
        "Hash-Lengths: " + strconv.Itoa(sequenceMatches) + "," + strconv.Itoa(weakChecksumLength) + "," + strconv.Itoa(strongChecksumLength) + "\n" +
        "URL: " + opts.Url + "\n" +
        "SHA-1: " + strFileChecksum + "\n\n"

    return checksum, strHeader, outputFileName

}

func sha1HashFile(path string, fileChecksumChannel chan []byte) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    hasher := sha1.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(hasher, file); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fileChecksumChannel <- hasher.Sum(nil)
}

func computeChecksum(f *os.File, blocksize int, fileLength int64, weakLen int, strongLen int, fileDigest hash.Hash, blockDigest hash.Hash) ([]byte, []byte) {

    checksumBytes := make([]byte, 0)
    block := make([]byte, blocksize)

    fileChecksumChannel := make(chan []byte)
    go sha1HashFile(f.Name(), fileChecksumChannel)

    for {
        read, err := f.Read(block)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if read < blocksize {

            blockSlice := block[read:blocksize]
            for i := range blockSlice {
                blockSlice[i] = byte(0)
            }

        }

        rsum := computeRsum(block)

        unsignedWeakByte := make([]byte, 4)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(unsignedWeakByte, uint32(rsum))

        tempUnsignedWeakByte := unsignedWeakByte[len(unsignedWeakByte)-weakLen:]
        checksumBytes = append(checksumBytes, tempUnsignedWeakByte...)

        blockDigest.Reset()
        blockDigest.Write(block)
        strongBytes := blockDigest.Sum(nil)

        tempUnsignedStrongByte := strongBytes[:strongLen]
        checksumBytes = append(checksumBytes, tempUnsignedStrongByte...)

    }

    fileChecksum := <- fileChecksumChannel

    checksumBytes = append(checksumBytes, fileChecksum...)

    return checksumBytes, fileChecksum

}

 // [ASK] A lot of type casting happen here, not sure if it's a good practice in Go
func strongChecksumLength(fileLength int64, blocksize int, sequenceMatches int) int {
    // estimated number of bytes to allocate for strong checksum
    d := (math.Log(float64(fileLength))+math.Log(float64(1+fileLength/int64(blocksize))))/math.Log(2) + 20

    // reduced number of bits by sequence matches
    lFirst := float64(math.Ceil(d / float64(sequenceMatches) / 8))

    // second checksum - not reduced by sequence matches
    lSecond := float64((math.Log(float64(1+fileLength/int64(blocksize)))/math.Log(2) + 20 + 7.9) / 8)

    // return max of two: return no more than 16 bytes (MD4 max)
    return int(math.Min(float64(16), math.Max(lFirst, lSecond)))
}

// [ASK] A lot of type casting happen here, not sure if it's a good practice in Go    
func weakChecksumLength(fileLength int64, blocksize int, sequenceMatches int) int {
    // estimated number of bytes to allocate for the rolling checksum per formula in
    // Weak Checksum section of http://zsync.moria.org.uk/paper/ch02s03.html
    d := (math.Log(float64(fileLength))+math.Log(float64(blocksize)))/math.Log(2) - 8.6

    // reduced number of bits by sequence matches per http://zsync.moria.org.uk/paper/ch02s04.html
    rdc := d / float64(sequenceMatches) / 8
    lrdc := int(math.Ceil(rdc))

    // enforce max and min values
    if lrdc > 4 {
        return 4
    } else {
        if lrdc < 2 {
            return 2
        } else {
            return lrdc
        }
    }
}

// [ASK] A lot of type casting happen here, not sure if it's a good practice in Go
func computeRsum(block []byte) int {
    var a int16
    var b int16
    l := len(block)
    for i := 0; i < len(block); i++ {
        val := int(unsign(block[i]))
        a += int16(val)
        b += int16(l * val)
        l--
    }
    x := int(a) << 16
    y := int(b) & 0xffff
    return int(x) | int(y)
}

func unsign(b byte) uint8 {
    if b < 0 {
        return b & 0xFF
    } else {
        return b
    }
}

func calculateMissingValues(opts zsyncOptions.Options, f *os.File) zsyncOptions.Options {
    if opts.BlockSize == 0 {
        opts.BlockSize = calculateDefaultBlockSizeForInputFile(f)
    }
    if opts.Filename == "" {
        opts.Filename = f.Name()
    }
    if opts.Url == "" {
        opts.Url = f.Name()
    }
    return opts
}

func calculateDefaultBlockSizeForInputFile(f *os.File) int {
    fileInfo, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if fileInfo.Size() < 100*1<<20 {
        return BLOCK_SIZE_SMALL
    } else {
        return BLOCK_SIZE_LARGE
    }
}
```

Also, coming from Java background, I get use to modularize everything, including this Options struct onto other file. Am I suppose to modularize it?

```
package zsyncOptions

type Options struct {
    BlockSize int
    Filename  string
    Url       string
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Always return errors

Don't use `log.Fatal()` everywhere ! Instead, return the error with some context:

```
checksum, fileChecksum, err := computeChecksum(fileByte, options.BlockSize, weakChecksumLength, strongChecksumLength)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("fail to compute checksum: %v", err)
}
```

#### Write to the `bufio.Writer` directly

You are right, creating the header by appending strings is not the best way. We could instead write 
the header content directly to the `bufio.writer`:

```
buf := bufio.NewWriter(zsyncFile)
buf.WriteString("zsync: ")
buf.WriteString(version)
buf.WriteByte('\n')

buf.WriteString("Filename: ")
```

...

it also possible to do it in a single call with `fmt.Fprintf()`

```
    fmt.Fprintf(buf, `zsync: %s
Filename: %s
MTime: %s
Blocksize: %d
Length: %d
Hash-Lengths: %d,%d,%d
URL: %s
SHA-1: %s

%s`,
        version,
        fileInfo.Name(),
        fileInfo.ModTime().Format(time.RFC1123Z),
        options.BlockSize,
        fileLength,
        sequenceMatches, weakChecksumLength, strongChecksumLength,
        options.Url,
        hex.EncodeToString(fileChecksum),
        checksum,
    )
```

#### Read the file once

Reading a file is expensive, it should be done only once. It is possible to read the content of a file 
in a slice of bytes with the `io/ioutil` package

```
fileByte, err := ioutil.ReadFile(options.Filename)
```

you can then compute it's **SHA1 checksum** in one line:

```
fileChecksum := sha1.Sum(fileByte)
```

and then create a `*Reader` from it:

```
reader := bytes.NewReader(fileByte)
for {
        read, err := reader.Read(block)
        ...
}
```

This also allow us to get the **file length** as an int like this:

```
fileLength := len(fileByte)
```

#### Method parameters

Some params are unused or redundant, for example `path` and `options.Filename`, they should be removed. 
You can group params with same type for more readability:

```
func computeChecksum(fileByte []byte, blockSize int, weakLen int, strongLen int) ([]byte, []byte, error) {
```

can be written like this:

```
func computeChecksum(fileByte []byte, blockSize, weakLen, strongLen int) ([]byte, []byte, error) {
```

Go also allows **named return** for more clarity. It's usefull when a method returns two values of the same type like here. Method 
signature could be:

```
func computeChecksum(fileByte []byte, blockSize, weakLen, strongLen int) (checksum []byte, fileChecksum []byte, err error) {
```

#### Keep things simple

There is no need for **channels** and **goroutines** in this code, it just make the code harder to read. Try to keep the code clean and simple. If you face performance issues, profile the code and optimize the hotspot.

The `computeRsum` method could be simplified a bit to return an `int32` directly:

```
func computeRsum(block []byte) uint32 {

    a, b, l := 0, 0, len(block)

    for _, v := range block {
        if v < 0 {
            v = v & 0xFF
        }
        a += int(v)
        b += l * int(v)
        l--
    }
    return uint32(a<<16) | uint32(b&0xffff)
}
```

#### Use **const** block for constant

this block

```
var ZSYNC_VERSION = "0.6.2"
var BLOCK_SIZE_SMALL = 2048
var BLOCK_SIZE_LARGE = 4096
```

should be rewritten like this:

```
const (
    version        = "0.6.2"
    blockSizeSmall = 2048
    blockSizeLarge = 4096
)
```

**const** are immutable, and that's what we want here. Also note that CamelCase is preferred for naming constant in go

#### final version

```
package zsync

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "crypto/md5"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/binary"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Options struct {
    BlockSize int
    Filename  string
    Url       string
}

const (
    version        = "0.6.2"
    blockSizeSmall = 2048
    blockSizeLarge = 4096
)

func ZsyncMake(options *Options) {

    err := writeToFile(options)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func writeToFile(options *Options) error {
    file, err := os.Open(options.Filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fileByte, err := ioutil.ReadFile(options.Filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fileLength := len(fileByte)

    if options.Url == "" {
        options.Url = options.Filename
    }

    if options.BlockSize == 0 {
        if fileLength < 100*1<<20 {
            options.BlockSize = blockSizeSmall
        } else {
            options.BlockSize = blockSizeLarge
        }
    }

    sequenceMatches := 1
    if fileLength > options.BlockSize {
        sequenceMatches = 2
    }
    weakChecksumLength := weakChecksumLength(fileLength, options.BlockSize, sequenceMatches)
    strongChecksumLength := strongChecksumLength(fileLength, options.BlockSize, sequenceMatches)

    checksum, fileChecksum, err := computeChecksum(fileByte, options.BlockSize, weakChecksumLength, strongChecksumLength)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("fail to compute checksum: %v", err)
    }

    zsyncFile, err := os.Create(file.Name() + ".zsync")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zsyncFile.Close()

    buf := bufio.NewWriter(zsyncFile)
    buf.WriteString("zsync: ")
    buf.WriteString(version)
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("Filename: ")
    buf.WriteString(fileInfo.Name())
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("MTime: ")
    buf.WriteString(fileInfo.ModTime().Format(time.RFC1123Z))
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("Blocksize: ")
    buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(options.BlockSize))
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("Length: ")
    buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(int(fileLength)))
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("Hash-Lengths: ")
    buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(sequenceMatches))
    buf.WriteByte(',')
    buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(weakChecksumLength))
    buf.WriteByte(',')
    buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(strongChecksumLength))
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("URL: ")
    buf.WriteString(options.Url)
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.WriteString("SHA-1: ")
    buf.WriteString(hex.EncodeToString(fileChecksum))
    buf.WriteByte('\n')
    buf.WriteByte('\n')

    buf.Write(checksum)

    return buf.Flush()
}

func computeChecksum(fileByte []byte, blockSize, weakLen, strongLen int) ([]byte, []byte, error) {

    reader := bytes.NewReader(fileByte)

    checksumBytes := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    block := make([]byte, blockSize)
    unsignedWeakByte := make([]byte, 4)

    for {
        read, err := reader.Read(block)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("fail to read block: %v", err)
        }

        if read < blockSize {

            blockSlice := block[read:blockSize]
            for i := range blockSlice {
                blockSlice[i] = byte(0)
            }
        }

        rsum := computeRsum(block)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(unsignedWeakByte, rsum)

        checksumBytes.Write(unsignedWeakByte[len(unsignedWeakByte)-weakLen:])

        strongBytes := md5.Sum(block)
        checksumBytes.Write(strongBytes[:strongLen])
    }

    fileChecksum := sha1.Sum(fileByte)
    checksumBytes.Write(fileChecksum[:])

    return checksumBytes.Bytes(), fileChecksum[:], nil
}

func computeRsum(block []byte) uint32 {

    a, b, l := 0, 0, len(block)

    for _, v := range block {
        if v < 0 {
            v = v & 0xFF
        }
        a += int(v)
        b += l * int(v)
        l--
    }
    return uint32(a<<16) | uint32(b&0xffff)
}

func strongChecksumLength(fileLength, blocksize, sequenceMatches int) int {
    // estimated number of bytes to allocate for strong checksum
    d := (math.Log(float64(fileLength))+math.Log(float64(1+fileLength/blocksize)))/math.Log(2) + 20

    // reduced number of bits by sequence matches
    lFirst := float64(math.Ceil(d / float64(sequenceMatches) / 8))

    // second checksum - not reduced by sequence matches
    lSecond := float64((math.Log(float64(1+fileLength/blocksize))/math.Log(2) + 20 + 7.9) / 8)

    // return max of two: return no more than 16 bytes (MD4 max)
    return int(math.Min(float64(16), math.Max(lFirst, lSecond)))
}

func weakChecksumLength(fileLength, blocksize, sequenceMatches int) int {
    // estimated number of bytes to allocate for the rolling checksum per formula in
    // Weak Checksum section of http://zsync.moria.org.uk/paper/ch02s03.html
    d := (math.Log(float64(fileLength))+math.Log(float64(blocksize)))/math.Log(2) - 8.6

    // reduced number of bits by sequence matches per http://zsync.moria.org.uk/paper/ch02s04.html
    rdc := d / float64(sequenceMatches) / 8
    lrdc := int(math.Ceil(rdc))

    // enforce max and min values
    if lrdc > 4 {
        return 4
    }
    if lrdc < 2 {
        return 2
    }
    return lrdc
}
```

#### performance

New code is slightly faster:

```
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkWriteOld-4        10000        200830 ns/op       40815 B/op         43 allocs/op
BenchmarkWriteNew-4        10000        164985 ns/op       29272 B/op         27 allocs/op
```